# GKE GCE Ingress FrontendConfig redirect non-www to www

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I want to redirect all non-www traffic to www traffic. E.g. `mydomain.com` to `www.mydomain.com`

GKE Ingress (GCE) uses `Frontendconfig`. Is there a way to configure `FrontendConfig` to redirect non-www traffic to www traffic.

Followed this guide (https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-features) to create `FrontendConfig`. In that guide there is no mention of such feature.

Comment: can you please share your Ingress config/yaml file.

Answer (score 2):

I am also looking for same feature. As i use google managed ssl certificates for my domains, only option is to use `gce` ingress. I managed to do this with following work around now.

I have a Nginx sidecar container, on top of my web app container and does this redirection. Example Nginx configuration is as below.

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Catch all configuration as below.

```
server {

    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  _;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000; # my web app
    }

}
```